# remove object if string starts with @"type(music)"

Tags: ios, string, nsmutablearray, compare

If have an NSMutableArray with many Strings in it.
Is it possible to remove all Objects who start with "type(music)"?
Array looks like:

```
[0] = type(movie),name...
[1] = type(music),name...
[2] = type(movie),name...
[3] = type(movie),name...
[4] = type(music),name...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to remove objects that start with "type(music)".

```
NSMutableArray *array = ...;
for (NSString *string in array) {
    if ([string hasPrefix:@"type(music)"]) {
        [array removeObject:string];
    }
}
```